# on error not firing for youtube images

Tags: jquery, youtube, youtube-javascript-api

```
    $("#myimg").on('error', function () {
        console.log("image load error");
    }).attr("src", "http://img.youtube.com/vi/6pxRHBw-k8M/DOESNOTEXIST.jpg");
```

on error never fires, tested on Chrome and Firefox

Answer (score 1):

If you try to load a bad image from youtube, it returns a 404 but it also returns an image.  So the browser doesn't consider it an error.  Check for it using XMLHttpRequest (tested in Chrome, Firefox, IE, Edge)

```
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var img = $("#myimg");
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 404) {
            console.log("image load error");
        }
    }
    xhr.open('GET', img .attr('src'));
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.send();
```